# Why does the radius of convergence use limsup

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to get some intuition for the radius of convergence, denoted as
    ${R} = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}}$. Why is it $\limsup$ and not $\liminf$ if both describe the end behavior of $|c_n|$? Why not take any value between $\liminf$ and $\limsup$?

Comment: What part of [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius) do you not understand? It basically comes down to asking why the Root Test uses limsup

Comment: Because the limit itself may not exist. And because that is what the theorem is.

Answer (score 0):

That is  because of the very definition of the radius of convergence: it is the *upper bound* of the moduli of the  set of $z$s such that $\;\smash{\displaystyle \sum_n} c_nz^n$, and by *Cauchy's criterion*n the series converges absolutely  if
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\lvert c_nz^n\rvert}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\lvert c_n\rvert}\,\lvert z\rvert<1.$$

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this formula for the radius of convergence is a corollary to the Root Test. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) for a proof of this. Accordingly, we can rework your question into **"Why does the Root Test use $\limsup$ instead of $\lim$ or $\liminf$?"**

---

The critical thing here is that the proof of this theorem relies on comparison to a geometric series, which *requires* us to show that $|a_n| < q <1$  for some $q$ for all $n$ larger than some $N_0$.

Avoiding any technical details, suffice to say that taking the $\limsup$ makes sure that we get the greatest long-term maximum of $a_n$, which allows that necessary inequality to work by ensuring no long-term maxima of $a_n$ "escape" our bounds.

---

More technically, knowing that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}<1$ holds allows us to conclude that the inequality above holds within some small enough neighborhood.